# Doze mode suspends foreground service

Tags: android, android-service, foreground-service, android-doze-and-standby

I am writing a data logger app and I need to make an http request every 5 minutes exactly. The user is aware of the battery drain and that's ok for me. I am using a foreground service with the appropriate notification for that and I have a handler thread to witch I post runnable tasks every 5 minutes. It seems that when the phone enter DOZE MODE the thread is suspended and no runnables are executed. Is that normal behaviour or I am missing something?
Any help on how to do that will be appreciated.

**Service code that starts the thread:**

```
private void startTheForegroundService() {   
      NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainService.this);
      builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
      startForeground(1000, builder.build());

      httpThread = new HttpThread("Ping Thread", Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
      httpThread.start();
      httpThread.loop();
}
```

**Thread code:**

```
public class HttpThread extends HandlerThread {
   public Handler mHandler;

   public HttpThread(String name, int priority) {
      super(name, priority);
   }

   public synchronized void waitUntilReady() {
      mHandler = new Handler(getLooper(), new Handler.Callback() {
         @Override
         public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            return false;
         }
      });
   }

   public void loop() {
      waitUntilReady();
      mHandler.post(new Runnable(){
      @Override
      public void run() {
         //code for the http request.
       }
     });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is that normal behaviour

Yes, for the Doze mode in Android 6.0, which triggers when the app has been stationary for an hour or so. The M Developer Preview extends Doze mode, such that it also partially triggers even when the device is moving, though I think your scenario would continue to work in that case.

> The user is aware of the battery drain

The user can add you to the battery optimization whitelist (Settings > Apps > (gear icon) > Battery Optimization).

Comment: I have the app whitelisted. The you music streaming apps (foreground services) continue to fetch data when the device is in DOZE mode? My handler doesn't trigger at all.

Comment: @GiorgosOikonomou: "I have the app whitelisted" -- hmmmm... "The you music streaming apps (foreground services) continue to fetch data when the device is in DOZE mode?" -- I haven't run a streaming music app for an hour-plus on Android 6.0 without being on a charger. Perhaps Android handles apps with the audio focus differently. "My handler doesn't trigger at all" -- are you sure the service hasn't been stopped? You might also consider `ScheduledExecutorService` instead of your `Handler`-based approach, and see if you have better luck with that.

Comment: ScheduledExecutorService Jobs stop working once the app  is cleared from multi-tasking tab (multi-tasking - - > kill apps)

Comment: @ShivamGaur: Yes. `ScheduledExecutorService`, `Handler`, and any other in-process timing solution only works when the process is running.

Comment: @CommonsWare Foreground Services override doze mode, meaning that will still be alive and never get killed. Something else is wrong here

Comment: @Nick: Doze mode has nothing do to with anything being "killed".

Comment: @CommonsWare my mistake. Can you have a quick look here ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53579449/background-service-doesnt-get-killed-when-in-doze-mode is a friend's question. Thank youu

Comment: @Nick im trying to figure out if foreground services run in doze mode still . is there predictable behavior across versions